# How to subtract two lists in python

Tags: python, list, zip, subtraction

I can't figure out how to make a function in python that can calculate this:

```
List1=[3,5,6]
List2=[3,7,2]
```

and the result should be a new list that substracts List2 from List1, `List3=[0,-2,4]`!
I know, that I somehow have to use the zip-function. By doing that I get:
`([(3,3), (5,7), (6,2)])`, but I don't know what to do now?

Answer (score 40):

Try this:

```
[x1 - x2 for (x1, x2) in zip(List1, List2)]
```

This uses `zip`, list comprehensions, and destructuring.

Comment: I like this way to do it.. I just can't get it to work (I haven't been working in python for a very long time)!
I did this:
def differences(xs,ys):
    [x1-x2 for (x1,x2) in zip(xs,ys)]?

Comment: I used [np.subtract(x1, x2) for (x1, x2) in zip(List1, List2)] and it worked!

Answer (score 21):

This solution uses [numpy](https://numpy.org/). It makes sense only for largish lists as there is some overhead in instantiate the numpy arrays. OTOH, for anything but short lists, this will be blazingly fast.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [3,5,6]
>>> b = [3,7,2]
>>> list(np.array(a) - np.array(b))
[0, -2, 4]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), as @Matt suggested. you can also use [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) - more specifically, the `imap()` function:

```
>>> from itertools import imap
>>> from operator import sub
>>> a = [3,5,6]
>>> b = [3,7,2]
>>> imap(int.__sub__, a, b)
<itertools.imap object at 0x50e1b0>
>>> for i in imap(int.__sub__, a, b):
...     print i
... 
0
-2
4
```

Like all itertools funcitons, `imap()` returns an iterator. You can generate a list passing it as a parameter for the `list()` constructor:

```
>>> list(imap(int.__sub__, a, b))
[0, -2, 4]
>>> list(imap(lambda m, n: m-n, a, b)) # Using lambda
[0, -2, 4]
```

**EDIT**: As suggested by @Cat below, it would be better to use the `operator.sub()` function with `imap()`:

```
>>> from operator import sub
>>> list(imap(sub, a, b))
[0, -2, 4]
```

Comment: `operator.sub` is more generic than `int.__sub__`. And has less underscores.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus excellent suggestion. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Yet another solution below:

```
>>> a = [3,5,6]
>>> b = [3,7,2]
>>> list(map(int.__sub__, a, b)) # for python3.x
[0, -2, 4]
>>> map(int.__sub__, a, b) # and for python2.x
[0, -2, 4]
```

**ADDITION:** Just check for the [python reference of `map`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) and you'll see you could pass more than one iterable to `map`

Comment: I didn't know that `map()` accepts more than one iterable. This is great!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in the following way

```
List1 = [3,5,6]
List2 = [3,7,2]
ans = [List1[i]-List2[i] for i in range(min(len(List1), len(List2)))]
print ans
```

that outputs `[0, -2, 4]`

Comment: Note that `xrange` is python 2 only, in python 3 `range` does the same thing.